# Keep game running while awaiting response?

Tags: c, opengl, udp, winsock, glut

I am making a multiplayer game, and every frame, the player's position must be sent to the server, where it will receive all the other players' positions as a response.

I added this line to make my code non-blocking:

```
u_long one = 1; // Giggety
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &one);
```

But now the problem is, unless I enable my own blocking code (while loop), I can't receive the other players' positions from the server.

```
while(recvfrom(sock, receiveBuffer, 255, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, &sockaddr_in_sizePtr) <= 0) {
}
// Do stuff with response
```

But since I do this, the game lags really badly, because the local game isn't running until I get a response.

I figured that the solution would just be to call my display function in the while loop, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Another problem is that I am using UDP sockets which means the data may not even reach me, in which case, it needs to timeout. So I added this:

```
time_t timer;
time(&timer);
while(recvfrom(sock, receiveBuffer, 255, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, &sockaddr_in_sizePtr) < 0) {
    display(); // Doesn't stop lag
    if(timer != time(NULL)) return; 
}
```

But now, I get times where it's literally 1 frame per second. Which is awful.

Can someone shed some light on how to keep the game running, and have it listening for sockets, simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every interactive simulation programm will run some nonblocking main loop. At some point in that loop you collect all the data that's arrived from the outside. If some new data arrived over the network you read it and process it into your programs state. If nothing arrived you just continue the main loop as usual.

However for this scheme to work your SO receive buffers must be large enough so that they can accumulate a lot of incoming packets for you to receive.

So what you do is something like

```
while(running) {
    if( hasDataArrivedOn(socket) ) {
        receiveFrom(socket);
    }
    
    if( isThereUserInput(mouse) ) {
        processMouseMovement();
    }

    if( isThereUserInput(keyboard) ) {
        processKeypresses();
    }

    simulate();

    display();
}
```

That "hasDataArrivedOn" function is actually another ioctl, namely the `FIONREAD` which returns the number of octets received in the last packet or 0 if there's no packet pending (also if the last received UDP packet did contain no payload a 0 is returned; your programm must be able to deal with this, otherwise it can be DoSed by being flooded with UDP packets containing no payload).

---

#### Update – GLUT idle callback variant

```
void idle()
{
    if( hasDataArrivedOn(socket) ) {
        receiveFrom(socket);
    }

    simulate();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This has helped me quite a lot. But I can't run a while loop, since it just crashes the app. I have to simply bind each glut function, EG: glutDisplayFunc(display); glutIdleFunc(idle);

Comment: Replace "while loop" with GLUT idle function, sans the input processing (which is done by callbacks); socket operations stay the same. See answer update.